# Liquibase / PostgreSQL problem: ? operator becomes ??

Tags: postgresql

I've been using Liquibase for a few months in a pre-production context, and just ran into this mystery issue.

It appears that the source code using the JSON `?` operator in Postgres is getting created in the database as `??` which is not valid.

For example, this source code
`WHERE f.filter_object::JSONB ? 'patient_status';`

appears like this when I view the SQL in pgAdmin
 `WHERE f.filter_object::JSONB ?? 'patient_status';`

Is there some setting that may be controlling this translation?
Our changesets use the sqlFile tag, if that matters.

Comment: It is somehow valid though. The JDBC driver accepts `??` as an "escape sequence" for the JSON operator `?` to avoid ambiguity with the parameter placeholder `?` If that really is a problem you could try to use a different operator. `f.filter_object::jsonb ?|  array['patient_status']` should perform in a similar way.

Comment: Btw: why isn't `filter_object` not already a `jsonb` column?

Comment: Why is this in the database to start with?  Does liquibase store its own source code in the database?  Is this part of a sql or plpgsql function?  Are you finding this in pg_stat_statements?

Comment: That's an interesting point about the jdbc driver (used by liquibase),.  This project is in .net and the npgsql driver does not escape it.  Although I can't even use the function from pgAdmin when it has the ```??``` there.
The ```filter_object``` here is a parameter passed in to the function, and it's currently passed as ```text``` hence the cast.  I don't expect that changing it to jsonb would matter but I can try that.

Comment: Liquibase doesn't store the source code -- it's a db deployment suite.  I provide it with xml files that point to the actual source code. and it deploys the changes for me.  
This is in a function that takes in a json object (e,g, ```{"patient_status":[1,4,7]}```  and returns some data based on that.
So that ```??``` is in the database because liquibase incorrectly translated my ```?``` in that function into ```??```.   Good questions.  
Need to check on the pg_stat statement.